# Recreate catalogue from breadcrumbs

Tags: mysql, scrapy, breadcrumbs, catalog

I have a little puzzle.

I use scrapy for parsing supplier website.

I want to do some trick. I want to recreate catalogue from breadcrumbs.

Does anyone know the algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's pseudocode based on some PHP code I wrote to convert breadcrumbs into a [Closure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462).

```
while ($breadcrumbs = fetch()) {
  $chain = explode("/", $breadcrumbs); -- assume "/" is the breadcrumbs separator
  $pathlength = count($chain) - 1;
  $child = $chain[$pathlength];
  foreach ($chain as $ancestor) {
    print $ancestor, $child, $pathlength;
    $pathlength--;
  }
}
```

The output is the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the categories in the catalog.